# Making a basic Haskell type an instance of a new typeclass

Tags: haskell

Say I'm trying to define a new typeclass in Haskell, and among other things, it must have a + operation:

```
class Foo a where
    (+) :: a -> a -> a
```

(In practice the typeclass Foo would have more stuff, but let me stop here to keep this minimal.)

Now, I want to make the basic "Integer" type an instance of Foo; and as far as the + operation goes, I just want to keep the usual addition, which is already defined. How do I do that?

Needless to say, the following makes no sense:

```
instance Foo Integer where
    (+) x y = x+y
```

It loops forever when I ask Haskell to compute 2+3, but I suppose that's to be expected! I also tried putting nothing at all:

```
instance Foo Integer
```

This compiles, but then when I ask for 2+3 I get "No instance nor default method for class operation +". Again, it makes sense...

But how do we do that then?

I guess it's a general question "about the namespace", I mean, when two typeclasses use the same names, what happens? In my case, I get issues when trying to make a type (Integer) an instance of two typeclasses with such a name clash (Num and Foo).

From reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757498/haskell-why-is-part-of-num-typeclass), I'm now afraid that what I'm asking for is just prohibited...

Comment: I'm realizing that I could do this within a module, with "import qualified Prelude" at the start, and then "instance Foo Prelude.Integer where  (+) x y = x  Prelude.+  y" or something... right? and then if I import my newly created module, does it all work? how does Haskell understand "2+3" ?

Comment: Right, I think you're barking up the wrong tree. As you mentioned -- you could ìmport qualified Prelude` and write every addition symbol as `Prelude.+`, but that seems...wildly unnecessary. Why does `Foo` have to use the `+` operator? If you simply change it to something unique, all this craziness goes away :)

Comment: @Adam: to take a very mathematical example (but i am, after all, a working mathematician...), you could imagine that Foo is really called AbelianGroup, so that the elements of a type of this class can be added, but NOT multiplied, so they don't belong to Num. Yet it is very natural to use + and not some other symbol... while elements of type "Integer" are certainly examples, among others.

Comment: PS you could rephrase my question as: how do you define a weaker version of Num, or of any typeclass, where some functions are not defined?

Comment: What would you need a "weaker" version for? (fyi, Idris' (and I think purescript's) version of Num is weaker than Haskell's, only requiring (*), (+), and fromInteger)

Comment: @Samuel: having a version of Num that does not require the type to belong to Eq and Show would be very useful, I can think of many examples (eg all functions Integer -> Integer...) And having a model for abelian groups, just having +, is a natural thing for a mathematician.

Comment: There is http://hackage.haskell.org/package/groups-0.4.1.0/docs/Data-Group.html, which builds groups and abelian groups on top of monoid, using the <> operator. Also- Num has no superclasses (it doesn't require Show or Eq)

Comment: From figure 6 in https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html#numbers I had deduced that Num required Eq and Show...?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a "higher-order" typeclass that would define `(+)`,   an instance of which would be a "regular" typeclass that provides a particular set of laws for `(+)` to obey in *its* instances . To the best of my knowledge, there is no such thing :)

Comment: Interesting; the [definition of `Num` in GHC](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Num.html#Num) doesn't make it a subclass of `Eq` or `Show`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to call your operation `+`, and you want to define it in terms of the `+` from Prelude, you can do it like this:

```
import Prelude (Integer, print)
import qualified Prelude ((+))

class Foo a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a

instance Foo Integer where
  (+) x y = x Prelude.+ y

main = print (2 + 3 :: Integer)
```

This will output 5.

To prove that the definition of `main` is really using our new `+` operator and not the original one, we can change our definition of `+`:

```
import Prelude (Integer, print)
import qualified Prelude ((+))

class Foo a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a

instance Foo Integer where
  (+) x y = x Prelude.+ y Prelude.+ 1

main = print (2 + 3 :: Integer)
```

This will output 6.

Comment: As you can see from the comments, this is what I had eventually in mind. Because this is definitely the right answer to my specific question, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9):

To give a specific solution, something like this would work without having to deal with clashing with (+):

```
class Foo a where
  (<+>) :: a -> a -> a

infixl 6 <+>

instance Foo Integer where
  (<+>) = (+)
```

Now your class Foo has its own operator, and the fixity declaration means that (<+>) will be parsed the same way as (+).

Comment: "parsed the same way as (+)", in what sense is it the same way? (do you just mean "with the same associativity properties" ?) Anyway, I really need (want...) to use +...

Comment: "infixl 6" means that (<+>) is left associative with a precedence of 6 (in haskell, operators can have a precedence from 0-9, with 0 being lowest and 9 being highest). Left associative means that if you have an expression 

1 <+> 2 <+> 3 <+> 4

it will be parsed as (((1 <+> 2) <+> 3) <+> 4); the operations will be performed from left to right. This is the same way (+) behaves.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you'd do this the same way in Haskell as in a pure math setting. You're trying to implement an Abelian group (it seems from your comments), which I understand (as someone who hasn't taken a mathematics course since High School) to be a group of type `a` where there exists a function `f :: a -> a -> a` such that `f x y = f y x`.

Contrast that with Haskells built-in (and oft-used) Monoid class and you'll see why I say Haskellers may approach this differently. Monoids are a group of type `a` where there exists a function `f :: a -> a -> a` such that `f x (f y z) = f (f x y) z` (and additionally, but unrelated, a value `k` such that `f x k = x`). It's representing associativity rather than commutativity, but is otherwise identical.

Monoids are represented as such:

```
class Monoid a where
  mempty :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  mconcat :: [a] -> a
```

and several are defined, like `Sum`

```
newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }
instance Num a => Monoid (Sum a) where
  mempty = 0
  mappend (Sum x) (Sum y) = Sum (x+y)
  -- mconcat is defined as `foldr mappend mempty`
```

Note that it doesn't try to redefine `(+)` here. In fact it defines its own operator as a synonym for `mappend`: `(<>)`. I recommend using a similar syntax with your Abelian group.

```
class Abelian a where
  (|<>|) :: a -> a -> a  -- or similar
```

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell, you can use your own `Prelude` instead of the standard one, and there are multiple existing [alternative preludes](https://guide.aelve.com/haskell/alternative-preludes-zr69k1hc). E.g. [numeric-prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) defines [`(+)` in `Algebra.Additive.C`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.3/docs/Algebra-Additive.html).

Comment: absolutely! NumericPrelude seems great. But I was wondering if you could achieve some of its functionality in an elementary way (re-writing the Prelude is far beyond what I can personally do, and at the same time, I'd like to understand what I use, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

**a programmer's approach**   As others have said, it is probably best if you forfeit the convenient notation for additive and multiplicative monoids that is widely used in the mathematics community, and rather think of monoid in a more abstract fashion — as a distinct algebraic structure with a distinct operation that, generally, has nothing to do with addition and multiplication in number rings, of which the `Num` typeclass may be considered an approximate formalization. The Haskell type system is relying on you to make sure that same names refer to same things, and distinct names refer to distinct ones — this simple and logical rule helps it avoid confusion. This is why the monoidal operation of any monoid is usually referred to with a lozenge `<>` sign. *(Actually, the operation on* initial *monoids is sometimes denoted `++`, because of tradition.)*

It is also somewhat illogical, but considered practical, that `Num` for usual numbers is defined first *(and even on the hardware level)*, and the constituting monoids are extracted afterwards:

`base-4.11.1.0:Data.Semigroup.Internal`

```
...
198 instance Num a => Semigroup (Sum a) where                                                            
199         (<>) = coerce ((+) :: a -> a -> a)                                                           
...
227 instance Num a => Semigroup (Product a) where
228         (<>) = coerce ((*) :: a -> a -> a)
...
```

— So it happens that `+` gets occupied long before any abstract algebra comes into play.

**an algebraist's approach**   Nevertheless, it is very much possible to define a ring out of a type with two monoids:

```
{-# language FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# language FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# language UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# language TypeApplications #-}

module MonoidsField where

import Prelude (Integer, Semigroup, (<>), Monoid, mempty, Show, show)
import Data.Coerce

newtype Sum a = Sum { getSum :: a }

newtype Product a = Product { getProduct :: a }

data N = Z | S { predecessor :: N}

-- | Substract one; decrease.
dec :: Coercible a (N -> N) => a
dec = coerce predecessor

instance Show N
  where
    show Z = ""
    show x = '|' : show (predecessor x)

instance Semigroup (Sum N)
  where
    u <> (Sum Z) = u
    u <> v = coerce S (u <> dec v)

instance Monoid (Sum N)
  where
    mempty = Sum Z

instance Semigroup (Product N)
  where
    u <> (Product Z) = coerce (mempty @(Sum N))
    u <> v = let (*) =         (<>) @(Product N)
                 (+) = coerce ((<>) @(Sum N))
             in u + (u * dec v)

instance Monoid (Product N)
  where
    mempty = Product (S Z)

(+) :: Monoid (Sum a) => a -> a -> a
x + y = getSum (Sum x <> Sum y)

(*) :: Monoid (Product a) => a -> a -> a
x * y = getProduct (Product x <> Product y)

class PseudoRing a

instance (Monoid (Sum a), Monoid (Product a)) => PseudoRing a
  where
    -- You may add some functions that make use of distributivity between the additive and
    -- multiplicative monoid.

-- ^
-- λ (S (S (S Z))) + (S (S Z))
-- |||||
-- λ (S (S (S Z))) * (S (S Z))
-- ||||||
```

— As you see, the `PseudoRing` class does not add any operations by itself, but it does make sure that the two monoids it requires are defined. If you instantiate it, it is implied that you have ensured that the axiom of distribution holds.

As this example suggests, a subclass may be thought of as including in itself all the operations defined for its superclasses. So, it is a possibility that you proclaim `instance Num a => Foo a` and get to re-use the definition of `+`. You may then go as far as to define *"partial"* instances of `Num` for your own types that a priory will not have a definition for all the required methods. This approach is obviously unsafe, confusing and overall not advisable, but it may be just what you need, especially if decorated with an appropriate [scientific license](http://matt.might.net/articles/crapl/). So, your example becomes:

```
class Foo a

instance Num a => Foo a
```

---

Let me know if any of the above requires clarification!

Comment: Thanks, very interesting. By the way, ultimately my solution will be to use -XRebindableSyntax. Not only does this NOT load the prelude, so I'll get rid of Num entirely; but also, one can now redefine fromInteger (to be of type Integer -> Integer and equal to Prelude.id), so that literals are interpreted as "Integer" and not Num a => a. So Num is entirely gone from my life, and there are now plenty of available solutions.

Comment: @Pierre Would the source code be available? I am keen on taking a look.

Comment: just use `{-# LANGUAGE RebindableSyntax #-}`followed by `import qualified Prelude` and then `fromInteger :: Integer -> Integer` with finally `fromInteger = Prelude.id`. Then as in the accepted answer, for example (or whatever else you want to do without Num!). I found the trick as an answer to a question on this site :-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have answered, the easiest option is to pick a new name for the operator.  This is the approach that most existing packages take, so that users of the library can continue using `Num` as usual.

As the OP notes in the comments, it is also possible to import `Prelude` qualified, and define `+` however you want.  Any other modules that want to use your new `+` will need to do the same.  They can either not import Prelude (via `import Prelude ()` or `NoImplicitPrelude`), or import it qualified.  This is pretty reasonable in a large codebase, where everyone knows the local convention and you can provide instances for all the types you use.